# Connecting Radio Button to Database using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got trouble inputing the radio button value to database, when i choose "submit" it won't add into database. This is the form view:

```
<?php
$form = array(
        'no pengujian' => array(
                    'name' => 'NO_PENGUJIAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'form_field',
                    'value' => set_value('NO_PENGUJIAN', isset($form_value['NO_PENGUJIAN']))),
        'id kendaraan' => array(
                    'name' => 'ID_KENDARAAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'form_field',
                    'value' => set_value('ID_KENDARAAN', isset($form_value['ID_KENDARAAN']))),
        'no kendaraan' => array(
                    'name' => 'NO_KENDARAAN',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'form_field',
                    'value' => set_value('NO_KENDARAAN', isset($form_value['NO_KENDARAAN']))),
        'lampu' => array(
                    'name' => 'LAMPU',
                    'size' => '30',
                    'class' => 'radio',
                    'value' => set_value('LAMPU', isset($_POST['LAMPU']))),
        'submit' => array(
                    'name' => 'submit',
                    'id' => 'submit',
                    'value' => 'Simpan'
                    )
                    );
?>
<h2><?php echo $breadcrumb ?></h2>
<!-- pesan start -->
<?php if (! empty($pesan)) : ?>
    <div class="pesan">
        <?php echo $pesan; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
<!-- pesan end -->

<!-- form start -->
<?php echo form_open($form_action); ?>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('No Pengujian', 'NO_PENGUJIAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form['no pengujian']); ?>
    </p>
    <?php echo form_error('NO_PENGUJIAN', '<p class = "field_error">', '</p>');?>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Id Kendaraan', 'ID_KENDARAAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form['id kendaraan']); ?>
    </p>
    <?php echo form_error('ID_KENDARAAN', '<p class="field_error">', '</p>'); ?>    
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('No Kendaraan', 'NO_KENDARAAN'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input($form['no kendaraan']); ?>
    </p>
    <?php echo form_error('NO_KENDARAAN', '<p class="field_error">', '</p>'); ?>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_label('Lampu', 'LAMPU'); ?>
        <input type ="radio" name = "lulus" value="Lulus"/> Lulus
        <input type ="radio" name = "lulus" value= "Gagal"/> Gagal
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php echo form_submit($form['submit']); ?>
        <?php echo anchor('pengujian', 'Batal', array('class' => 'cancel')) ?>
    </p>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

This is the controller (tambah is "insert" function to database)

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed');
class Pengujian extends MY_Controller
{
    public $data = array(
                    'modul'         => 'pengujian',
                    'breadcrumb'    => 'Pengujian',
                    'pesan'         => '',
                    'pagination'    => '',
                    'tabel_data'    => '',
                    'main_view'     => 'view_pengujian/pengujian_view',
                    'form_action'   => '',
                    'form_value'    => '',
                    'option_uji'    => '',
                    );
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Pengujian_model', 'pengujian', TRUE);
        $this->load->helper('form');
        //$this->load->model('Penguji_model', 'penguji', TRUE);
    }
    public function index($offset = 0)
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('no_pengujian_sekarang', '');
        $pengujian = $this->pengujian->cari_semua($offset);
        if ($pengujian)
        {
            $tabel = $this->pengujian->buat_tabel($pengujian);
            $this->data['tabel_data'] = $tabel;
            $this->data['pagination'] = $this->pengujian->paging(site_url('pengujian/halaman'));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->data['pesan'] = 'Tidak ada data pengujian';
        }
        $this->load->view('template', $this->data);
    }
    public function tambah()
    {
        $this->data['breadcrumb']   = 'Pengujian > Tambah';
        $this->data['main_view']    = 'view_pengujian/pengujian_form';
        $this->data['form_action']  = 'pengujian/tambah';

        //$penguji = $this->penguji->cari_semua();
        //if($penguji)
        //{
         //   foreach($penguji as $row)
           // {
             //   $this->data['option_pengujian'][$row->id_penguji] = $row->penguji;
            //}
        //}
        //else
        //{
            $this->data['option_pengujian']['00'] = '-';
          //  $this->data['pesan'] = 'Data penguji tidak tersedia. Silahkan isi dahulu data penguji.';
            // if submit

            if($this->input->post('submit'))
            {
                if($this->pengujian->validasi_tambah())
                {
                    if($this->pengujian->tambah())
                    {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', ' Proses tambah data berhasil');
                        redirect('pengujian');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->data['pesan'] = 'Proses tambah data gagal';
                        $this->load->view('template', $this->data);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->load->view('template', $this->data);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('template', $this->data);
            }
        }
```

This is the model:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Pengujian_model extends CI_Model
{
    public $db_tabel    ='pengujian';
    public $per_halaman = 100;
    public $offset      = 0;
    public function cari_semua($offset = 0)
    {
        if (is_null($offset) || empty($offset))
        {
            $this->offset = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->offset = ($offset * $this->per_halaman) - $this->per_halaman;
        }
        return $this->db->select('NO_PENGUJIAN, ID_KENDARAAN, NO_KENDARAAN, LAMPU, EMISI, REM, WAKTU_UJI')
        ->from($this->db_tabel)
        ->limit($this->per_halaman, $this->offset)
        ->order_by('NO_PENGUJIAN', 'ASC')
        ->get()
        ->result();
    }
    public function buat_tabel($data)
    {
        $this->load->library('table');
        $tmpl = array('row_alt_start' => '<tr class="zebra">');
        $this->table->set_template($tmpl);
        $this->table->set_heading('No', 'No Pengujian', 'Id Kendaraan', 'No Kendaraan', 'Lampu','Emisi','Rem', 'Waktu Uji', 'Aksi');
        $no = 0 + $this->offset;
        foreach ($data as $row)
        {
            $this->table->add_row(
            ++$no,
            $row->NO_PENGUJIAN,
            $row->ID_KENDARAAN,
            $row->NO_KENDARAAN,
            $row->LAMPU,
            $row->EMISI,
            $row->REM,
            $row->WAKTU_UJI,
            anchor('pengujian/edit/'.$row->NO_PENGUJIAN,'Edit',array('class' => 'edit')).' '.
            anchor('pengujian/hapus/'.$row->NO_PENGUJIAN,'Hapus',array('class' => 'delete','onclick'=>"return confirm('Anda yakin menghapus data ini?')")));
        }
        $tabel = $this->table->generate();
        return $tabel;
    }
    public function paging($base_url)
    {
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config = array(
                'base_url'      => $base_url,
                'total_rows'    => $this->hitung_semua(),
                'per_page'      => $this->per_halaman,
                'num_links'     => 4,
                'use_page_number'   => TRUE,
                'first link'    => '&#124;&lt; First',
                'last link'     => 'Last &gt;&#124;',
                'next link'     => 'Next &gt;',
                'prev_link'     => '&lt; Prev',
                );
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        return $this->pagination->create_links();
    }
    public function hitung_semua()
    {
        return $this->db->count_all($this->db_tabel);
    }
    private function load_form_rules_tambah()
    {
        $form = array(
                array(
                'field' => 'NO_PENGUJIAN',
                'label' => 'no pengujian',
                'rules' => 'required'
                ),
                array(
                'field' => 'ID_KENDARAAN',
                'label' => 'id kendaraan',
                'rules' => 'required'
                ),
                array(
                'field' => 'NO_KENDARAAN',
                'label' => 'no kendaraan',
                'rules' => 'required'
                ),
                array(
                'field' => 'LAMPU',
                'label' => 'lampu',
                'rules' => 'required'
                ),
                );
            return $form;
    }
    public function validasi_tambah()
    {
        $form = $this->load_form_rules_tambah();
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($form);
        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    public function tambah()
    {
        $pengujian = array(
                'NO_PENGUJIAN' => $this->input->post('NO_PENGUJIAN'),
                'ID_KENDARAAN' => $this->input->post('ID_KENDARAAN'),
                'NO_KENDARAAN' => $this->input->post('NO_KENDARAAN'),
                'LAMPU' => $this->input->post('lampu[]'),
                //'EMISI' => $this->input->post('EMISI'),
                //'REM' => $this->input->post('REM')
                );
        $lulus = $_POST["lulus"];
        //$statement = "INSERT INTO pengujian VALUES($lulus)"
        $this->db->insert($this->db_tabel, $pengujian);
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

I got no trouble in the formfield. The trouble is the radio button "lampu"

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do, I think, is to check where it's going wrong. I usually do this, in this case, by checking if the value is being passed back to the controller and model. This way you understand better what's going on inside your code. Do something like this:

In the model:

```
     public function tambah()
{
    // Check to see if we get a value. If not, do the same in the controller
    var_dump($this->input->post('lampu'));
    exit;

    $pengujian = array(
            'NO_PENGUJIAN' => $this->input->post('NO_PENGUJIAN'),
            'ID_KENDARAAN' => $this->input->post('ID_KENDARAAN'),
            'NO_KENDARAAN' => $this->input->post('NO_KENDARAAN'),
            'LAMPU' => $this->input->post('lampu[]'),
            //'EMISI' => $this->input->post('EMISI'),
            //'REM' => $this->input->post('REM')
            );
    $lulus = $_POST["lulus"];
    //$statement = "INSERT INTO pengujian VALUES($lulus)"
    $this->db->insert($this->db_tabel, $pengujian);
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps a bit....